# How to declare property using GetType in LINQ Include

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently working on an API and the library I'm using needs to initialize most of its components. It is initialize by using .include.

A sample call would be: `context.Load(context.Projects, proj => proj.Include(p => p.Name))`

As much as possible, I don't want to include a lot of fields since it will take longer to execute the query. So one of my idea was to use `GetType().GetProperty()`, which looks like this:

```
context.Load(context.Projects, proj => proj.Include(
    p => p.Name,
    p => p.GetType().GetProperty(customFieldName)
));
```

My assumption was that when I do this I will get the property, but it seems it creates a different object. Is there any way I can do this?

Edit: The idea is that the `customFieldName` is given by the user, so for example the user gave `Id` I'm hoping to get the equivalence too `p.Id` in the Include statement. So I can return the value of that object to user

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes, my current setup is WCF Web Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework also allows you to include properties based on their name as a string. In this way you can decide the property to include at runtime. So your code should now look something like this.

```
context.Load(context.Projects, proj => proj.Include("Name", customFieldName));
```

In case you are looking into nested properties (for ex: `Name` is a class with properties `FirstName` and `LastName`), you could use dot to specify the exact property to include (`"Name.FirstName"`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. your solution should have work, but the Microsoft Library is overriding the Include that it should be `Expression<Func<PublishedProject,object>>` which I'm guessing is the equivalent of `p => p.(property)`. I tried doing `p => "property"` but it does not work as well.

Comment: Oh that's strange! .Net framework supports this. See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Technically your solution is right and will mark that as the answer but in my case I need the object property which can be done by using `[]` so it should look like `p => p["property"]` and that works